# How to use JSONObject effective in your android project

Tags: android, json

Recently my project has json requirement, but I've never use json before, so i want to know how to use json effective.
    I use Volley as my network lib, which support json default,  know I can get the JSONObject or JSONArray response, and can get the data by the method such as :

```
String name = response.optString("name");
```

obviously it's not a good idea, I want to generate java class as my response data, use a model class to wrap the JSONObject or use gson、jackson to generate a java class, anybody can share your experience? thanks.

Comment: Why is that no good idea? JSONObject is already a representation. If you want to convert the JSONObject to a custom model, do so. Just iterate the JSONObject, JSONArray or whatever and create your own datastructure, using normal ArrayLists, HashMaps or whatever you need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are millions of implementation and usecase about JSON+Android, but belows are common approaches.

1. I use gson in order to de/serialize an object as below. It is more reliable than sequence-sensitive `Parcelable` conversion for me.

   ```
    public static String toJson(Object obj){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(obj);
    }

    public static Object fromJson(String json, Class clazz) 
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(json, clazz);
    }
   ```
2. In case of json communication with server, [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) gives neat json i/o handling.
3. Or, I use [loopj async library](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) and implement static JSON deserializer as all properties can be handled on my own.

   ```
    public class Question {
        public int count;
        public String text;
        public Date generateTime;

        public static Question FromJson(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
            Question result = new Question();
            result.category = jsonObject.optInt("Count");
            result.text = jsonObject.optString("Text", "");
            result.generateTime = DateTime.parse(jsonObject.optString("GenerateTime")).toDate() : new Date();
            return result;
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: I choose jackson at first, but I found it's lib.jar has 6000+ method which let my project nearly reach 65535 problem, so I use gson instead. thanks